# How can a variable have a number and an undefined type?

Tags: javascript, variables, undefined

I'm having trouble with a variable I set with a prompt. So I checked the variable in the console, and did not understand the result.

My questions is, how can a variable have a number for its value and undefined for its type?

Here is the code.

```
const inputNumber = prompt("Input a number");
console.log("inputNumber is " + inputNumber);
console.log("inputNumber's type is " + inputNumber.typeof);
```

and here is the output in the console if I put 5 in the prompt.

```
"inputNumber is 5"
"inputNumber's type is undefined"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator, not a property `typeof`, which is `undefined` for each string.

BTW, `inputNumber` is always a string, because of [`prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt).

For conversion to a number, you need to parse it ([`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)/[`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)) or take an implicid conversion with [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus).

```js
const inputNumber = prompt("Input a number");
console.log("inputNumber is " + inputNumber);
console.log("inputNumber's type is " + typeof inputNumber);
```